# Apache Jena - got 3 identical results for one query

Tags: java, sparql, jena

This is my first question here on StackOverflow. 
I'm using Apache Jena in order to query DBPedia and the results i got are pretty strange.
Here's my code, with a simple query :

```
    String sparqlQuery = "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> select ?o where { <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent> rdfs:subClassOf  ?o}";
    System.out.println("Query : " + sparqlQuery);
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQuery);
    QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query); 
    ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
    ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
    qexec.close();
```

And this is what i got in response :

`<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing> 
 <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing> 
 <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing>`

Any idea why i don't get a single Resource ? I tried with other Resources, same problem.

Thanks for your help and have a nice day !

Comment: Probably it cannot prove the 3 instance's equality nor further properties.

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty strange, when I test your query on http://dbpedia.org/sparql, I got only one resource.

Can you check that there are three result in your `ResultSet` ?

```
int count = 0;
while( results.hasNext() ){
  results.next();
  count++;
}
System.out.println("I see "+count+" rows !");
```

As workaround, you could use the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
SELECT DISTINCT ?o
WHERE { 
  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent> rdfs:subClassOf  ?o
}
```

Comment: Yeah i did the same test and got one resource aswell.
"I see 3 rows !", so this is not a display problem ;)
I think i'm gonna use DISTINCT, if someone has an explanation let me know !
Thanks Nizil.

Answer (score 2):

The query is sent to dbpedia so it is that giving three answers.  Jena only formats the results.

It might be because there are 3 triples in different named graphs - the default dbpedia graph is the union of all named graphs.

Try:

```
select *{ GRAPH ?g { <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent> rdfs:subClassOf  ?o} }
```

Also check the results returns : issue the query with wget or curl and see the bytes sent back.

(The response you show does not correspond the ResultSetFormatter output)